# Embedding struct vs pointer to struct in struct used as pointer

Tags: go, struct

If I have a struct type `A` which is used as a pointer (has pointer receivers only, the constructor returns `*A`, etc.), what is the difference between embedding a struct type `B` as `B` versus `*B`?

That is, what is the difference between

```
type B struct {...}
type A struct {
    B
    // ...
}
```

and

```
type B struct {...}
type A struct {
    *B
    // ...
}
```

For example, is there ever copying of the embedded field?

Edit: I should also mention that the embedded struct `B` only has pointer receivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zero values of the two structures are different, which can be a significant ergonomic difference.

Consider an embedded type

```
type B struct {
    X int
}

func (b *B) Print() { fmt.Printf("%d\n", b.X) }
```

If we embed this directly as an object

```
type AObj struct {
    B
}
```

then the zero value of type `AObj` includes an embedded *object* of type `B`, which also has its zero value, and therefore we can safely

```
var aObj AObj
aObj.Print() // prints 0
```

But if we instead embed a pointer

```
type APtr struct {
    *B
}
```

the zero value of this struct has a nil pointer value, and we can't really use it directly.

```
var aPtr APtr
aPtr.Print() // panics
```

Objects get copied in hopefully the way you might expect.  If you create a new `AObj` object, it gets a copy of the embedded `B`.

```
aObj2 := aObj
aObj.X = 1
aObj2.Print() // prints 0, because it has a copy
```

If you create a new `APtr` object, it gets a copy of the `*B`, which means it shares the underlying concrete object.

```
aPtr.B = &B{}
aPtr2 := aPtr
aPtr.X = 1
aPtr2.Print() // prints 1, because both objects point at the same B
```

Runnable example at https://play.golang.org/p/XmOgegwVFeE

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple example program. A `structAPtr` embeds a pointer, a `structAVal` embeds a struct `structB` directly:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type structB struct {
    foo int
}

type structAPtr struct {
    bar *structB
}

type structAVal struct {
    bar structB
}

func main() {
    // referencing bStruct
    b1 := structB{foo: 12}

    aPtr := structAPtr{bar: &b1}
    fmt.Println("Before assignment:")
    fmt.Printf("aPtr.bar.foo = %d, b.foo = %d\n", aPtr.bar.foo, b1.foo)

    aPtr.bar.foo = 42
    fmt.Println("After assignment:")
    fmt.Printf("aPtr.bar.foo = %d, b.foo = %d\n", aPtr.bar.foo, b1.foo)

    // copying bStruct
    b2 := structB{foo: 12}

    aVal := structAVal{bar: b2}
    fmt.Println("Before assignment:")
    fmt.Printf("aVal.bar.foo = %d, b.foo = %d\n", aVal.bar.foo, b2.foo)

    aVal.bar.foo = 42
    fmt.Println("After assignment:")
    fmt.Printf("aVal.bar.foo = %d, b.foo = %d\n", aVal.bar.foo, b2.foo)
}
```

The int `structB.foo` is used to demonstrate whether `structB` changes when manipulated inside of `structAPtr` or `structAVal`.

This program outputs:

```
Before assignment:
aPtr.bar.foo = 12, b.foo = 12
After assignment:
aPtr.bar.foo = 42, b.foo = 42 <------------ both changed
Before assignment:
aVal.bar.foo = 12, b.foo = 12
After assignment:
aVal.bar.foo = 42, b.foo = 12 <------------ only assignee changed
```

Looking at the result shows:

- changing the value of the *pointer* to `structB` changes `structB`
- changing the value of the copied version `structB` in `structAVal` leaves `structB` unaffected (it is still `5`, even after `42` was assigned to `aVal`)

---

Edit:

If your `structB` has only pointer receivers anyways, the intended behavior is probably such that changing `structB` in `strucA` updated both of them. That's scenario 1 in my example and requires a pointer for sure. From **A Tour of Go**:

> Methods with pointer receivers can modify the value to which the receiver points [...]. Since methods often need to modify their receiver, pointer receivers are more common than value receivers.

---

Hope that helps!